# JS - call function twice with one argument and two variables

Tags: javascript, function, class, onclick, modal-dialog

The JS :

```
function modalf(id){
var modal = document.getElementById(id);

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
window.document.onkeydown = function (esc){
if (!esc) esc = event;
if (esc.keyCode == 27)
{
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
}
```

The call :

```
modalf('register');
modalf('login');
```

The small part of html :
Button open modal :

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='block'">Login</button>
```

modal:

```
<div id="login" class="modal">
<span>modal text</span>
</div>
```

The problem, that i have 2 modals, login and register, and i want to run my function each time i need it.
i created the Js function but when i tried to run it twice like :
modalf('register');
modalf('login');

only first one working, i tried to check if it work separatelyת and it's work perfectly.

Someone have best solution for this? maybe something good that i could use function for more than 2 modals... maybe 10 for future.

best regards,
Orr.

Comment: does it work if you put the second call in a setTimeout?

Comment: As Sagar said the onclick and onkeydown is override they self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.
There are some little differences between `onclick` and `addEventListener`.
Is this met your requirements?

```js
modalf('register');
modalf('login');

function modalf(id){
var modal = document.getElementById(id);

var a=function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
window.addEventListener('click',a);
var b= function (esc){
if (!esc) esc = event;
if (esc.keyCode == 27)
{
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
window.addEventListener("keyup",b);
}
```

```css
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    padding: 14px 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Float cancel and signup buttons and add an equal width */
.cancelbtn,.signupbtn {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

/* Add padding to container elements */
.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 15px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Clear floats */
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* Change styles for cancel button and signup button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .cancelbtn, .signupbtn {
        width: 100%;
    }
    span.psw {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}
/* The "Forgot password" text */
span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='block'">Sign Up</button>

<!-- The Modal (contains the Sign Up form) -->
<div id="register" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
      <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>



<!-- Button to open the modal login form -->
<button onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='block'">Login</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="login" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'" 
class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <!--<img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">-->
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
    </div>

      <div class="clearfix container">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
      </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: prefect for 90%, when i use `modalf('register');
        modalf('login');` so the keydown not working on the register only for last one. could you answer me what's the idea behind of this? why now it's works better? because of `window.addEventListener('click',a);
` ?

Comment: **so the keydown not working on the register only for last one.**
Sorry I can't get you clearly. Can you explain it.

Comment: onclick is an attribute(like id,class,etc.). it changes each time. but addEventListener can have any number of Event Listener and it will never override current eventListener

Comment: please go : https://jsfiddle.net/9zdw0wd9/1/   and try to press on signup button, it will play modal, than try to close it with ESC key, no effect. but when you open the login, you can close it with ESC key. after you explained me about the difference of addEventListener and onclick, i guess they just override each other.

Comment: The same should be implemented. Instead of onkeypress, you are supposed to use addEventListener.

Comment: I think that now it works as your requirement. Check it out

Comment: for first, i love you :) , you learnt me a lot today, the idea of addEventListener is awesome. please check my solution for idea, please let me know if it good as yours, for performance, the updated code : https://jsfiddle.net/9zdw0wd9/2/

Comment: yes it is nice. always try to use addEventListener if you want to add multiple actions to same element.
If you think I helped you, consider an upvote and also mark it as answer, then it may help others too.
feel free to ask any query.
Regards 
Sagar V

Answer (score 0):

Think this will help you.
**After running snippet, allow 2-3 seconds for it to get compiled. Then only the clicks will work**

```js
function modalf(elem,id,id2){
var modal = document.getElementById(id);
var modal2 = document.getElementById(id2);
elem.addEventListener('click',function(){
  modal.style.display="block";
  modal2.style.display="none";});

window.document.onkeydown = function (esc){
if (!esc) esc = event;
if (esc.keyCode == 27)
{
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="modalf(this,'login','register');">Login</button>
modal:

<div id="login" class="modal">
<span>LOGIN</span>
</div> 
<br />
<button onclick="modalf(this,'register','login');">Register</button>
modal:

<div id="register" class="modal">
<span>REGISTER</span>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, but not perfect ;) . You built trigger between login and register, but your forgot, if i need to create more modals at the same page, it will not work perfectly. also i'm clicked out of the modal, it's not showoff this code not working anymore : `window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}`

Comment: make a snippet, what have you done so far and then describe the problem. Then only we can understand clearly

Comment: answer added. Please check it. @MarcoGanzo